# Swift Simple XOR Encryption

Tags: swift, xor

I am trying to do a simple xor encryption routine in Swift.  I know this is not a particularly secure or great method but I just need it to be simple.  I know how the code is implemented in Javascript I'm just having trouble translating it to Swift.

Javascript:

```
function xor_str()
{
  var to_enc = "string to encrypt";

  var xor_key=28
  var the_res="";//the result will be here
  for(i=0;i<to_enc.length;++i)
  {
    the_res+=String.fromCharCode(xor_key^to_enc.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  document.forms['the_form'].elements.res.value=the_res;
}
```

Any help you could provide would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would propose an extension to String like this.

```
extension String {
    func encodeWithXorByte(key: UInt8) -> String {
        return String(bytes: map(self.utf8){$0 ^ key}, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
```

From the inside out,

1. The call to self.utf8 creates a byte array, `[UInt8]`, from the string
2. map() is called on each element and XOR'ed with the key value
3. A new String object is created from the XOR'ed byte array

Here is my Playground screen capture.
[image]

**UPDATED: For Swift 2.0**

```
extension String {
  func encodeWithXorByte(key: UInt8) -> String {
    return String(bytes: self.utf8.map{$0 ^ key}, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that xor'ing all bytes of a UTF-8 string does generally *not* produce a valid UTF-8 string. For example. `"Hello World".encodeWithXorByte(200)` will crash.

Comment: You are correct.  However using only printable keys will always generate printable encodings; UInt8(0x1C)...UInt8(0x7F). Another serious problem was my use of self.utf8.  Javascript's charCodeAt() returns at least a 16bit or possibly 21bit unicode value.  The string iterator and encoding needs to be changed appropriately in the code above.

Comment: Thanks @PriceRingo! This code worked perfectly for me. I realize this may not be a technically correct thing to do but it gets the job done well here.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer with a comment yet, but Price Ringo, i noticed a couple problems with your sandbox..

the last line has 2 errors, you should actually XOR it with the original encrypted UInt8 and you are not "decoding" the encrypted string..

you have...

```
println(str.encodeWithXorByte(0))
```

where you should have..

```
println(encrypted.encodeWithXorByte(28))
```