# Swift Biginteger xor encrypt/decrypt

Tags: swift, encryption, hex, biginteger, xor

I'm new to Swift, now I just want to translate java xor encrypt/decrypt code to Swift, which is used for transactions between server and client. Below is the Java xor code:

```
public static String encrypt(String password, String key) {
    if (password == null)
        return "";
    if (password.length() == 0)
       return "";

    BigInteger bi_passwd = new BigInteger(password.getBytes());

    BigInteger bi_r0 = new BigInteger(key);
    BigInteger bi_r1 = bi_r0.xor(bi_passwd);

    return bi_r1.toString(16);
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String key) {
    if (encrypted == null)
        return "";
    if (encrypted.length() == 0)
        return "";

    BigInteger bi_confuse = new BigInteger(key);

    try {
        BigInteger bi_r1 = new BigInteger(encrypted, 16);
        BigInteger bi_r0 = bi_r1.xor(bi_confuse);

        return new String(bi_r0.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And I've searched a lot about swift xor encryption and tried the answer in the links below:

[XOR Encryption in Swift IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358325/xor-encryption-in-swift-ios)

https://coderwall.com/p/timkvw/simple-xor-encryption-and-decryption-in-swift-playground-code

[Swift Simple XOR Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144796/swift-simple-xor-encryption)

But all of them can't get the same encryted string compared with my java code, now my java code was live, and there's no way to change it.

I thought it might caused by the hexadecimal, but in swift, I can't find anywhere about swift xor hexadecimal.

So what I need is the swift code can get the exact same encrypted string as java code I've pasted, the encrypted string generated by my java client can be decrypted in my iOS client.

Thanks very much whoever can help me out of this! I've get into this a whole day!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, below is the code.

Based on the great work at https://github.com/lorentey/BigInt

```
func encrypt(str:String, key:BigUInt)->String
{
    let value = BigUInt(str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    let encrypt = key ^ value
    return String(encrypt, radix: 16)
}

func decrypt(str:String, key:BigUInt)->String
{
    let value = BigUInt(str, radix: 16)!
    let decrypt = key ^ value
    return String(data: decrypt.serialize(), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
}
```

Thanks again for everyone whoever contributed to the the BigInt library, that's why the code looks so simple.

Comment: Do you have Swift 4 version?